# WkWebView reloads Youtube video upon rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, wkwebview

I currently have a WKWebView which plays YouTube videos inline. Upon rotation to horizontal orientation, I have the view change constraints to full screen - however, this causes the YouTube video inside to reload before continuing to play.

Is there a way to prevent it from reloading, and have it just continue playing?

Michael

Comment: I suggest you avoid mutating constraint arrays and simply assemble a layout that is flexible enough to work for different orientations.